# How can I isolate the cause of poor performance whne running X-Plane 11 in windowed mode?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, steam

I used to run X-Plane 11 (flight simulator) when I was on Ubuntu 16.04 and had no performance issues other than when I pushed the limitations of my hardware. So, everything worked exactly as expected. However, after upgrading the 18.04, I can only achieve good performance when running XP11 in fullscreen mode *and* when XP11 has focus. If I carry my mouse to another monitor and shift focus to another program (e.g., firefox), my entire computer stutters. Furthermore, if I try to run the game in windowed mode my computer stutters horribly regardless of which program has focus. I do not believe my problem is with a *necessary* bottleneck in the system, because my CPU, GPU, and RAM are never maxed out when running the game. Furthermore, XP11 *says* I'm getting 40-60FPS while I'm experiencing the stuttering.

I submitted a support ticket to the XP11 devs, but received a very short response to the effect of "Sorry, we don't support Linux". This leaves me a bit uncertain about how to proceed. It *seems* like the problem is on the OS side rather than with XP11, but I'm not certain how to begin eliminating possible causes. Here are some relevant details:

System Specs:

- Graphics card: [Sapphire Radeon R9 280](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_Rx_200_series#Radeon_R9_280)
- Graphics drivers: Default Open-Source AMD drivers
- CPU: i5-4690K
- RAM: 16GB DDR3
- Three monitors (can provide more detail if needed)
- Game is X-Plane 11 version 11.36r2 run through Steam

I'm considering trying to use a different set of drivers, but in the past when I've experimented with graphics driver's I've ended up a sad panda for one reason or another (e.g., monitors go blank when booting up). Furthermore, I have no other issues with other games or programs so I'm a bit concerned about creating more problems. In any case, I'm willing to try messing around with graphics drivers if I need to, but I wanted to get some input before I start toying with an otherwise perfectly stable system.

Comment: Are you using X11 or Wayland?

Comment: @AndroidDev Using the instructions I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325972), I think I'm using X11.


EDIT: I should add that I don't remember ever making this decision explicitly. I'm not even sure what "Wayland" and X11" are. Perhaps using X11 is the default for a typical install of Ubuntu 18.04?